# Active filter for low capacitance AC coupled input

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, interface, active-filter

[image]
I need to interface an AC coupled sensor with rest of my system. The sensor I am working with produces approx. 10V peak with 10V of DC offset but it has a very small series resistance about 50fento.

Sensor operates at about 35KHz. My initial thought is to use an op-amp in inverting configuration for ease of bias setting (reference voltage at +IN). I also want this circuit to work as low pass filter.

The problem I face are reasonable component values.

I do not want to use feedback resistor value larger than 10Meg ideally I would like to reduce it while maintaining -3dB at 35KHz.

This however means that I would need to reduce C(feed) to maintain fc at 35KHz which leads to lower output amplitude in pass band.

Is there any other topology I could use?

My goal is to keep SNR in my system as high as possible and noise as low as possible.

Comment: Will your sensor mind being run into a virtual ground? What does "045pF" mean numerically?

Comment: Apologies it is missing a decimal point. It meant to be 0.45p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a very low input capacitance load CMOS Op Amp to work as a Charge Amplifier or TransImpedance Amp. (TIA)   [This research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4146279_MEMS-_and_probe-based_mass_data_storage_in_conventional_CMOS) shows how your BW and Cs can be loaded without the usual pF load attenuation.
Rin values of 1000 Gohm are possible in commercial packages but I have not looked for the lowest Cin specs [except for one](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/62689f.pdf) which is 100 fF.

The research design shows  Cin < 100 fF.